# Spark Standalone : how to avoid sbt assembly and uber-jar?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, databricks, apache-spark-standalone

I have `sbt.build` like that, to do Spark programming :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.1" withSources(),
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "3.0.0" withSources()
  ...
)
```

As my program use other libraries than Spark itself, I have to use `sbt assembly` to generate an uber Jar, that I can use as an argument to `spark-submit`, in order to run such spark application in my `spark standalone` cluster.

The resulting `uber-jar` output works like a charm.

However the compilation took a lot of time, and I find such method too slow to iterate in my development.

I mean, at every Spark application code change, that I want to test, i have to run another compilation that output the `uber-jar` with sbt, and each time, it takes very long (at least 5 minutes) to be done, before I can run it on my cluster.

I know that I may optimize a bit the `build.sbt` to faster a bit the compilation. But I think it will remain slow.

So, my question is, if you know that there are other methods that completely avoid to build an `uber-jar` ?

Ideally I think about a method, that I just have to trigger `sbt package` (lot faster than `sbt assembly`), and where I then just can tell at the `spark-submit` level or at the `spark standalone` cluster level, which additionnal jars to load.

However for instance, the `spark-submit` seems clear about that..

> application-jar : Path to a bundled jar including your application and **all dependencies**

.. so may be I have no other choice ..

Any pointers to speed up my Spark development with Scala, SBT, and additional librairies ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary that you put all dependent libraries into assembly/fat jar - they simply should be available to your application in the runtime.  This could be done differently:

- specifying individual jars via `--jars` - this could be cumbersome, especially if the jars themselves have a lot of dependencies
- specifying maven coordinates via `--packages` - in this case, you just provide dependency(-ies) and Spark fetches all of them with all of their dependencies
- copying all jars to every node of your cluster, so they will be picked up automatically.

See [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management) for more details.

Also, dependencies of the Spark itself shouldn't be packed into assembly - they need to be marked as `provided` instead

P.S. If you'll run your code on Databricks, then you can install libraries into the cluster via UI, or APIs, although you may still have a case when you need to put your libraries into assembly - this sometimes is required because of the dependencies conflicts